# String comparison in bash

Tags: bash

I guarentee that this is a rookie mistake, but I can't seem to get my if-elif-else statement working with comparing a string.

```
echo "What is your current OS?"
read $OS
if [ "$OS" == "Unix" ] 
then    
    echo "Unix is pretty good.."
elif [ "$OS" == "Linux" ]
then    
    echo "Open-source eh?"
elif [ "$OS" == "Windows" ]
then    
    echo "Microsoft owns the universe"
elif [ "$OS" == "OSX" ]
then    
    echo "Apple has control over you"
else    
    echo "Not a valid os type."
fi
```

Comment: First -- use `=`, not `==`, to be POSIX-compliant. Second -- `read OS`, not `read $OS`

Comment: The other answer may not look like a duplicate based on its title -- but the underlying problem is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading into `$OS`, which is the value of the `OS` variable.

You want to read into `OS`, and then access it with the sigil like so: `$OS`.

Answer (score 0):

To read into the variable `OS`, not into the variable *whose name is contained in* the variable `OS`, use:

```
read OS
```

not

```
read $OS
```

---

By the way -- this code would be far better written with a `case` statement:

```
case $OS in
  Unix) echo "Unix is pretty good.." ;;
  Linux) echo "Open-source eh?" ;;
  Windows) echo "Microsoft owns the universe" ;;
  OSX) echo "Apple has control over you" ;;
  *) echo "Not a valid os type." ;;
esac
```

By contrast, if you *do* want to use `test` (aka `[`), use `=` (which is POSIX-compliant), not `==` (which is a bash extension) for string equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$#" != 1 ]
then
  echo $0 OS
  exit
fi
case "$1" in
Unix)    echo 'Unix is pretty good..'       ;;
Linux)   echo 'Open-source eh?'             ;;
Windows) echo 'Microsoft owns the universe' ;;
OSX)     echo 'Apple has control over you'  ;;
*)       echo 'Not a valid os type.'        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Using a command-line argument rather than reading from stdin is a rather large change in behavior to make without commentary.